# Plural of "Tablet PC"?

Tags: grammar

Is the plural of "Tablet PC" "Tablet PCs"?

Is the phrase "There are many Tablet PCs" right?

Comment: Why do you think it may be wrong?

Comment: PC Tablets where PC is used as an adjective.

Comment: @Narasimham I'm guessing that you mean '_Tablet PCs_ where _Tablet_ is used as an adjective'. OP does not mention the reverse string. But if you take time to look at 'noun adjuncts', 'attributive nouns' here, you will see that in say _football manager_,  all linguists regard the pre-modifier _football_ as still being a noun rather than an adjective.

Comment: @Mick Some people say "PC" is a collective noun... Some people say that "PCs" are not very formal.

Comment: Like in Asprin tablets.. we state its content at first. may also conform to the grammar of the language of a non-English speaker.

Comment: @Narasimham What I want to ask is the plural of "Tablet PC".

Comment: I would use _tablet PCs_. Life's too short to worry about such things.

Comment: @Narasimham it is also "desktop PCs" and "laptop PCs". The personal computer is not a medicine, so "PC desktops" and "PC laptops" does not sound right.

Comment: When pluralization has a problem, okay to swap the noun and its adjective.

Comment: As mentioned, PC is a noun.

Comment: I do not believe that anyone says that PCs, a most technical term, is not formal. I do not believe that anyone uses PC as a collective noun. And I do not for a minute believe that they would be mistaken for a native speaker if they did.